# iPhone compose email interface designing

Tags: iphone, email, interface

Can someone please tell me the elements used to  create the 'compose email' page in the iPhone?

More specifically, what elements are used to create the light blue 'bubbles' that display the contacts in the To:/CC:/BCC: fields?

I need to make a screen similar to that, except populated with a data source of my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the library three20. It has a view controller for a customizable compose interface built-in.

http://github.com/facebook/three20/

Comment: a custom library that has the objects built in!? wow.. this is insanely cool.

thanks a million Jason!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).  In the MessageUI.framework.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been a little more specific. I want to create a view similar to that of the 'Compose Email' interface, except with the data sources replaced by my own.

Basically, instead of Contacts, I want to be able to use my own list to add objects using the 'bubble-like' interface.